# Using TypeScript Generics with Feature Checks

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working with new and legacy pieces of UI and for a new feature that is rolling out, am using a feature toggle to decide which piece of the UI to show. The back-end, for the new feature now returns a different model so, throughout my code base, I have to account for this by creating V2 versions of existing methods/properties.

Throughout my code, there is a lot of this:

```
let someCollection: ModelV1 | ModelV2;

this.featureEnabled
    ? someCollection = someCollection as ModelV2
    : someCollection = someCollection as ModelV1;
```

With the usage of TypeScript, I would like to create a generic function that would return to me whichever type I ask for and would abstract the feature check.

Another example is when I use the feature check to set a specific version of a property to a specific version of an array:

```
if (this.featureEnabled) {
    this.someCollectionV2 = this.usersV2.filter(user => user.selected);
} else {
    this.someCollection = this.users.filter(user => user.selected);
}
```

It's cumbersome to have this spread out over my code and it feels like a code-smell. How can I optimize this and make it more functional?

Answer (score 0):

The OOP way to handle this would be to define an interface which has all of the functionality that depends on whether the feature is enabled.  Then your main class stores an instance of a feature class which is either enabled or disabled.  The main class only needs to check in one place -- where it creates and stores the feature instance -- and after that it never needs to check again because both classes have the same interface.

In my opinion this is the way to go as it resolves all of the typescript issues and also removes lots of if statements and unnecessary branching. We don't even need to store the `featureEnabled` boolean because we don't need it.  Here's a dummy setup:

```
interface DependentFunctions {
    doSomething(): number;
}

class MyClass {

    private _handler: DependentFunctions;

    constructor(featureEnabled: boolean) {
        if ( featureEnabled ) {
            this._handler = new V2Class();
        } else {
            this._handler = new V1Class();
        }
    }

    exampleMethod() {
        const num = this._handler.doSomething();
    }

}

class V2Class implements DependentFunctions {
    doSomething() {
        return 2;
    }
}

class V1Class implements DependentFunctions {
    doSomething() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIQA4RAE22AMQFcQExgB7EAZ2QG8BYAKGVeRwoGUKBbCMABagA5gAoAlAC5kIIjwBG0ANzMAvs2YIANnGq0AsgE8Awjr30NLNhijAAbnEjIA%20gLi4t0aeiy58xUnIqahUmZjZkBGCwKCIyCihRGAhHIigIAFEQOHlPHGl5CgpPd3ELKwjWYBhkUWRk1PSsnLzkMsYKyojBYGoAOld3HE8oZABeGQgAd2QANQAmU11qCVCu1lVkCC1qFA71yp7%20wY9occmZ2YBGJb1V8PX1TqeH1ggADzgeDE99fgEKDgJOUDlEaGAZHJzkcBm5TlA%20hxuHweiAxOI1mwXkxsdplnNFmZaMBvp4%20OBaD5sHhwAEyJQaCC2EjeP8RMD9ut0mA0iBkPNMRs1JY8eZrrdiaSIOSwJTMNT-CR6cEmawWSihGiOa9KtzecgroLkE9VEA)

If you want to instead tackles typescript issues directly, then you can make use of [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) and [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

[Some Examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGwGoEYoF4oCIBu6uA3ALABQoksiKqATNnvvSRRQMbICGAzr1ABiASwBOvYKgjjhcAHZQA3hSiqovOAFsIAYTjJkEDsFlyAXDSRpMAH0t16ZcirUAzCN2ABXURACictwARoYIFkFw%20h5yTi6qwryCHt6%20AcGhABQAlBbAABYJUIWKGtp6BkYm8hbwVgwAvkpxaqq%20KQr5CQB07p4%20-oEhEAhOLfXs5C153HIIhrUo2U2TLWrCrlAZnbxdCUl9qYOZWVnLq%20dQHPISUJq0yEzbXaW6%20obGpsRQAPTfUNMCKjQBZoejNMZQFC8aDKFYXNRXOQ3O5WR4FHYvcrvKoxH5-BBwCC8OQAcmAUG4xi83AMICggVEojgAHcoNs2Xk4F4AOZ5KBmDLgtTjOFQEXNBIMEFLWHNEXi8hcPgCADKRnkCCkMnkZzUmLelVMNXuGCgdhBDFiot6KQG6WG4UihhmVpakvo0pRKGNdVs9lBOVu9yKAgtjFh8LaPg66J6yX6aSGIzlEymMzmEGlpwjF3Wmye7ulT31FQ%208hOuvhqkRyODOGLWlepZxX1%20-z4bPAwJNYNFEKhMKF5xr5K9D3rsZL2M%20ePbgK7-owQ7FKfICqV-CgABUCqJNdJeKYADxbyEAD2AEFmAgiURmAD5K%20pG1jDdVt%20fL9e2aIvNAAPyLowPp0OgrpuPGhz2mE25OAqnA8JughcqI%20Raoe8gnp%20V4IKGJp%20mGj45qoU5vuYsGphBBx2kmFinhAF44XhdSMIBwC-tAFiuDS0JwUAA)